# Error al hacer una consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo un pequeño problema con una consulta, estoy tratando de sumar las cantidades que existen en mi tabla detalle_ventas, lo que quiero hacer es sumar las cantidades que tengan el mismo producto_id y la misma fecha de vencimiento.

Ejemplo:

```
id_producto | fecha_vencimiento | Total
============|===================|========
1           | 2018-05-03        | 100
------------|-------------------|---------
1           | 2018-12-05        | 150
------------|-------------------|---------
2           | 2017-07-09        | 30
```

Hice esta consulta:

```
SELECT producto_id, fecha_vencimiento, SUM(cantidad) as cantidad FROM detalle_ventas WHERE fecha_vencimiento = fecha_vencimiento and producto_id = producto_id
```

Pero esta me SUMA todas las cantidades que hay en mi base de datos y no las separa como en el ejemplo.

```
id_producto | fecha_vencimiento | Total
============|===================|========
2           | 2018-05-03        | 280
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para el funcionamiento que deseas, a tú consulta le hace falta un agrupamiento `GROUP`:

```
SELECT producto_id, fecha_vencimiento, SUM(cantidad) as cantidad FROM detalle_ventas GROUP BY producto_id, fecha_vencimiento
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esperaré 9 minutos para aceptar la respuesta, me funcionó!

Comment: OK, Me alegra que te haya funcionado!!!